# connecting php to mysqli database error

Tags: php, mysqli

i am having a problem in connecting this with the database. Please help whats wrong on this code?

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','ecommerce');
//getting the categories
function getCats(){
    global $con;
    $get_cats="select * from categories";
    $run_cats=mysqli_query($con, $get_cats);
    while($row_cats = mysqli_fetch_array($run_cats)){
        $cat_id=$row_cats('cat_id');
        $cat_title=$row_cats('cat_title');
        echo "<li><a href='#'>$cat_title</a></li>";
    }
}
//getting the brands
function getBrands(){
    global $con;
    $get_brands="select * from brands";
    $run_brands=mysqli_query($con, $get_brands);
    while($row_brands = mysqli_fetch_array($run_brands)){
        $brand_id=$row_brands('brand_id');
        $brand_title=$row_brands('brand_title');
        echo "<li><a href='#'>$brand_title</a></li>";
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: What's the error

Comment: Why do you *think* something is wrong with the code?  What actual problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: If you are having connection issues check for the error, http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.connect-error.php.

Comment: Please use the `mysqli_query($con, $query) or die(mysqli_error($con));`. This will give you the error

Answer (score 1):

You are accessing the `$row_cats`-Array and `$row_brands`-Array wrong.

Use `[`and `]` instead of `(` and `)`